# UWP: AES encryption and decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, uwp, aes

I had a simple class to do some basic local encryption for Windows Phone 8. I wanted to use the class again in a new UWP Windows 10 app for the Windows Store. Unfortunately I cannot use the AesManaged class anymore.

I tried to use `Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core`, but I'm completely stuck.
This is the original class I used for Windows Phone 8. I must have found it somewhere on the internet back then.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace TestGame

{
    public class AesEnDecryption
    {
        private string AES_Key = "MYLiSQ864FhDevJOeMs9EVp5RmfC7OuH";
        private string AES_IV = "FoL5Tyd9sZclVn5A";

        public string AES_encrypt(string Input)
        {
            var aes = new AesManaged();
            aes.KeySize = 128;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(AES_Key);
            aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AES_IV);

            var encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
            byte[] xBuff = null;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    byte[] xXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Input);
                    cs.Write(xXml, 0, xXml.Length);
                }

                xBuff = ms.ToArray();
            }

            string Output = Convert.ToBase64String(xBuff);
            return Output;
        }

        public string AES_decrypt(string Input)
        {
            var aes = new AesManaged();
            aes.KeySize = 128;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(AES_Key);
            aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AES_IV);

            var decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor();
            byte[] xBuff = null;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    byte[] xXml = Convert.FromBase64String(Input);
                    cs.Write(xXml, 0, xXml.Length);
                }

                xBuff = ms.ToArray();
            }

            string Output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(xBuff, 0, xBuff.Length);

            return Output;
        }
    }
}
```

Does someone knows how to translate this for UWP Windows 10 apps?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using .NET Core, try `Aes.Create()` instead of `new AesManaged()`

Comment: **Never** reuse an IV; always use a new IV for each encrypted message. And that's assuming the key isn't actually hardcoded but passed as an argument for each user or something. Having them *both* hardcoded is just plain ... "not smart".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the Documentation about [SymmetricAlgorithmProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241478?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) and [CryptographicEngine.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241490)

I have here a little example, how to use these together:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

namespace CryptTest
{
    public class AesEnDecryption
    {

        // Key with 256 and IV with 16 length
        private string AES_Key = "Y+3xQDLPWalRKK3U/JuabsJNnuEO91zRiOH5gjgOqck=";
        private string AES_IV = "15CV1/ZOnVI3rY4wk4INBg==";
        private IBuffer m_iv = null;
        private CryptographicKey m_key;

        public AesEnDecryption()
        {

            IBuffer key = Convert.FromBase64String(AES_Key).AsBuffer();
            m_iv = Convert.FromBase64String(AES_IV).AsBuffer();
            SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider provider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);
            m_key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(key);
        }

        public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input)
        {

            IBuffer bufferMsg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(input), BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
            IBuffer bufferEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(m_key, bufferMsg, m_iv);
            return bufferEncrypt.ToArray();
        }

        public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] input)
        {
            IBuffer bufferDecrypt = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(m_key, input.AsBuffer(), m_iv);
            return bufferDecrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

When you want to use another Algorithm then `AesCbcPkcs7`, then you have to change the [SymmetricAlgorithmName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetricalgorithmnames.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried like this:

private void EncryptButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AesEnDecryption endec = new AesEnDecryption();
    byte[] toEncrypt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345");
    byte[] encrypted = endec.Encrypt(array);
}

But on the line:

IBuffer bufferEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(m_key, bufferMsg, m_iv);

I get the following error message: The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706F8).
I tried different lengths for toEncrypt (16, 32, 64, 128, 192).

Comment: Sorry for the bad layout of my previous comment :(

Comment: I will try it later again. And Update my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help me out on this. I really appreciate that. I can program some c#, but when it comes to encryption I'm hopeless. I try to study as much as I can, but as a beginner it's not always easy :(

Comment: @Robin Sry for my late reply: I tested again and had the same error. I tried a different keys and IV. When i am using a 256 key and a 16 IV it works nice. See the updated Answer

Comment: Thank you very much, TheTanic. It works very well now. I will mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner code

```
    public static async Task<bool> EncryptAesFileAsync(StorageFile fileForEncryption, string aesKey256, string iv16lenght)
    {

        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            //Initialize key
            IBuffer key = Convert.FromBase64String(aesKey256).AsBuffer();
            var m_iv = Convert.FromBase64String(iv16lenght).AsBuffer();
            SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider provider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);
            var m_key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(key);

            //secured data
            IBuffer data = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(fileForEncryption);
            IBuffer SecuredData = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(m_key, data, m_iv);
            await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(fileForEncryption, SecuredData);
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            success = false;
            DialogHelper.DisplayMessageDebug(ex);
        }
        return success;

    }
    public static async Task<bool> DecryptAesFileAsync(StorageFile EncryptedFile, string aesKey256, string iv16lenght)
    {

        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            //Initialize key
            IBuffer key = Convert.FromBase64String(aesKey256).AsBuffer();
            var m_iv = Convert.FromBase64String(iv16lenght).AsBuffer();
            SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider provider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);
            var m_key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(key);

            //Unsecured Data
            IBuffer data = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(EncryptedFile);
            IBuffer UnSecuredData = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(m_key, data, m_iv);
            await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(EncryptedFile, UnSecuredData);
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            success = false;
            DialogHelper.DisplayMessageDebug(ex);
        }
        return success;

    }
```