# AES Encryption in UWP for Xamarin Forms project

Tags: windows, xamarin, cryptography, uwp, aes

I have a couple simple encryption functions that I need to use in a new UWP app for Windows 10. Since AesManaged isn't available in UWP, I've looked at Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core docs and posts here, but can't seem to get it to work. For instance, I haven't found where to set padding. The two functions encrypt and decrypt the contents of a byte array buffer using a key also in a byte array.

```
    byte[] Buffer;

    private void EncryptBuff(byte[] sessionKey)
    {
        AesManaged myAes = new AesManaged();

        myAes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        myAes.KeySize = 128;
        myAes.Key = sessionKey;
        myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        ICryptoTransform encryptor = myAes.CreateEncryptor();
        Buffer = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
    }

    private void DecryptBuff(byte[] sessionKey)
    {
        AesManaged myAes = new AesManaged();

        myAes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        myAes.KeySize = 128;
        myAes.Key = sessionKey;
        myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = myAes.CreateDecryptor();
        Buffer = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
     }
```

Any help translating this to run in a UWP app would be greatly appreciated. This code is used for communicating with an existing hardware controller, so I can't change things to improve the security.

Also, this is for a Xamarin Android/iOS/UWP project, so from what I can tell, .NET Core isn't an option unfortunately. The original code works fine in Android/iOS, but not UWP.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41714595/3888657 Take a look at this answer. You can change the Mode/Padding via the AlgorithmName.

Answer (score 2):

While `AesManaged` isn't available in .NET Core 1.0 or 1.1, `Aes.Create()` is available.  If you replace

```
AesManaged myAes = new AesManaged();
```

with

```
Aes myAes = Aes.Create();
```

Everything will just work on the .NET Core / UWP packages.

Comment: Thanks bartonjs, but I forgot to say this is a cross platform Xamarin Forms app, so apparently no .NET Core. :-( Yours would be an awesome solution if I could use it though! Thanks.