# Port Java AES ECB encryption into UWP compatible C# Code

Tags: java, c#, encryption, cryptography

I am very new in the field of cryptography and have been stuck on this problem for two days.

I have a java code for **AES/ECB** encryption and I want my uwp app to use the same encryption technique but whatever I've tried so far gives different encryption results.
There are many answers on stackoverflow suggesting to use `RijndaelManaged` class, but this class is not available for **UWP**.

Here's java snippet

```
 public string encrypt(String input, string key) {
    SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);
    crypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    return Base64.encodeToString(crypted,Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713107/uwp-aes-encryption-and-decryption) to see how to encrypt/decrypt. However, you need a different (ECB so insecure) algorithm. So instead of the given CBC cipher mode you need to use `AesEcbPkcs7` from the [SymmetricAlgorithmNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetricalgorithmnames).

---

Notes:

- PKCS#7 is the same as PKCS#5 as used in the Java code, more info [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172);
- you of course don't need to use an IV for ECB mode, so strip that out;
- the UTF-8 encoding and base 64 decoding I'll leave out, it should be easy to do these encodings in any language/environment (the `Convert` and `UTF8Encoding` classes seem to be available for UWP apps).