# UWP: AES encryption and decryption for PDF file

Tags: pdf, encryption, uwp

Looking at answer solution posted by [@TheTanic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3888657/thetanic) at: [UWP: AES encryption and decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713107/uwp-aes-encryption-and-decryption)

The CryptTest sample is a huge help. It works for a simple string. I am reading a PDF file and some of the characters do not encrypt/decrypt correctly. For example, Bytes 10 thru 13 on the original file array had values 226, 227, 207, 211 before encryption. Once I have called encrypt and then decrypt back (with the same key and IV), they should have been the same (and most values are) but Bytes 10 thru 13 are all 63. Needless to say, the resulting PDF has the correct number of pages, but no content.  File sizes are exact. The file I am reading is in Windows storage. Need some ideas here.

I am using this code to read the file for the input parameter to the encrypt method call and then calling the Decrypt method with that result.

```
    byte[] toEncrypt = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

    byte[] Encrypted = endecryption.Encrypt(toEncrypt);

    byte[] Decrypted = endecryption.Decrypt(Encrypted);
```

Here is the sample code form the link above for ease of reference.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

namespace CryptTest
{
    public class AesEnDecryption
    {

        // Key with 256 and IV with 16 length
        private string AES_Key = "Y+3xQDLPWalRKK3U/JuabsJNnuEO91zRiOH5gjgOqck=";
        private string AES_IV = "15CV1/ZOnVI3rY4wk4INBg==";
        private IBuffer m_iv = null;
        private CryptographicKey m_key;

        public AesEnDecryption()
        {

            IBuffer key = Convert.FromBase64String(AES_Key).AsBuffer();
            m_iv = Convert.FromBase64String(AES_IV).AsBuffer();
            SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider provider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);
            m_key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(key);
        }

        public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input)
        {

            IBuffer bufferMsg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(input), BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
            IBuffer bufferEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(m_key, bufferMsg, m_iv);
            return bufferEncrypt.ToArray();
        }

        public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] input)
        {
            IBuffer bufferDecrypt = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(m_key, input.AsBuffer(), m_iv);
            return bufferDecrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Original file to be encrypted]
[image: After encrypt and decrypt]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` on the input. This isn't valid for binary data, and shouldn't be necessary for encryption or decryption (encryption is performed on binary data, not ASCII strings).

The values above 127 cannot be encoded into ASCII, and it looks like they're being converted to `?` (63).

Remove the "turn it into ASCII and then turn it back in to binary" step and it should work.

Comment: Thanks! I revmoved this line,           
 IBuffer bufferMsg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(input), BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8); 
and changed this one           
 IBuffer bufferEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(m_key, bufferMsg, m_iv);

 to            
IBuffer bufferEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(m_key, input.AsBuffer(), m_iv);
It works!